# Generating options and selecting the first result automatically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select

This is something I've struggled with for quite a while now. My objective is to populate the select box with a variable list of greetings and have it automatically select the first one instead of simply being a blank space.

```
<label>Check me to select: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected">
</label><br/>

<select> id="greetings">
    <option ng-repeat="greeting in MyCtrl.greetingList"
            ng-selected="selected">{{ greeting }}</option>
</select>
```

The ng-selected directive (and indeed the selected attribute, which would actually be a simpler solution) do indeed select an item from the list on form load, but it always defaults to the last item on the list. I could probably capture the first element in the list and generate the rest, but I can't help but think there's a more elegant solution out there. Any ideas?

By the way, I know ng-options is better than ng-repeat. The problem is that I need each of my options to have an ng-click directive. I can't achieve that with ng-options.

Comment: Simplest way is just use `ng-options` and set the value for the `ng-model` to first item in array in controller

Answer (score 0):

You should try `$first` plus assign a `model` to select. in this way

```
<select data-ng-model="greetings">
    <option data-ng-repeat="greeting in MyCtrl.greetingList"
                data-ng-selected="$first" data-ng-value={{greeting.id}}>{{ greeting }}</option>
</select>
```

There are some special properties too. All of them are as below

`$index`

`$first`

`$middle`

`$last`

`$even`

`$odd`